# Как подсчитать количество выполнений скрипта?

Tags: php

Собственно вопрос, как прибавлять к переменной +1 при каждом запуске? Мой пример показывает всегда $i = 1, а как сделать, чтобы $i увеличивалось на 1, не знаю.

```
<? 
$i = 0;

if ($i < 2) {
    echo 'Исход 1';
}
if ($i > 2 && $i < 6) {
    echo 'Исход 2';
}
if ($i > 6 && $i < 12) {
    echo 'Исход 3';
}
$i++;
?>
```

Comment: Пока пришло в голову записывать $i++ в файл и заменить $i = 0; на file_get_contents();

Comment: Писать можно в файл, в любой кеш, в какую-нибудь таблицу со статистикой в базе

Comment: Считать можно только записав в файл или базу

Answer (score 1):

Значение можно сохранить в PHP сессии

```
$i = $_SESSION['count'];

if ($i < 2) {
    echo 'Исход 1';
}
if ($i > 2 && $i < 6) {
    echo 'Исход 2';
}
if ($i > 6 && $i < 12) {
    echo 'Исход 3';
}
$i++;
$_SESSION['count'] = $i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сохранять значение в файле.

`data/` - путь к каталогу, нужно сделать доступным интерпретатору на чтение/запись.

```
$fp = fopen("data/counter.txt", "r+");
if(!$fp)$fp=fopen("data/counter.txt", "x+");
if(!$fp)$fp=fopen("data/counter.txt", "r+");
flock ($fp,LOCK_EX);
$counter= fgets($fp, 10)+1;
fputs($fp, $counter);
flock ($fp,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
echo $counter;
```

`flock` и третий `fopen` - на случай параллельного запуска скрипта.